# iPhone: Constants for a UI element's coordinate and size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, coding-style, constants

If I am making the user interface programmatically, what is the best way to store constants for a UI element's coordinate and size? `#define`, or `double const`? Should I be putting this in the .h, .m, or a separate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use `#define` for sizes etc, just under the `@implementation` line, writing `static CGFloat xx` etc is too long and unnecessary in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it:

Constants that need to be available to the entire project are in "Project-Prefix.pch" as `#define SOMECONST SOMEVAL`.

Constants that are only needed within the scope of a class go at the top of the `@implementation` (.m) file as `whatever const whatever whatevr`.

For example, wherever I use a `UITableView` in a view controller, I have this just below the `@implementation` line:

```
static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"com.cell.tableview.someviewcontrollername.iphone.universaltemplate.mycompany";
```

To be used in:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
```

Then, in Universal-Prefix.pch, I have `LOCATIONS_URL` which is needed in lots of places throughout the project:

```
#define LOCATIONS_URL [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/get_locations.php?uid=%@&device=%@", MY_BASE_URL, CLIENT_APP_UID, DEVICE_NAME]
```